# I'm trying to add sound and i've searched this site but here error comes file no found why?

Tags: java

KeyListener s;

```
    try {

        AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("x.wav"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
    }

    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
        System.out.println(uae);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException lua) {
        System.out.println(lua);
    }// TODO add your handling code here:
```

I have a file With name x.wav do i need to enter path or save it in its directory

Comment: Yes you need to use the path relative to the user's directory, relative to `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: You should be able to find similar problems and answerson this site easily as this type of question gets asked several times a day, and so you're likely framing your search wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file path only gives the file name, not the location. When your code is executing, the program knows that it is looking for `x.wav` but has no idea where to find it.

Make sure that you include the entire path name in the file object, like `C:\path\to\audio\file\x.wav`.

If you do not want to give the entire path name in the code, you would have to use `System.getProperty()` to get a relative directory for your path. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html lists some of the arguments that you can pass into the getProperty() method.